# How to write single component XML to install it on all versions of Joomla?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions, joomla1.7

I've written 4 different component xmls for 4 Joomla versions i.e v1.5, v1.6, v1.7 and v2.5.

All the 4 xmls are exactly same except only one line which specifies joomla version number.

```
For v1.5 :    <install type="component" version="1.5.0">
For v1.6 :    <install type="component" version="1.6.0">
For v1.7 :    <install type="component" version="1.7.0">
For v2.5 :    <install type="component" version="2.5.0">
```

Is is possible to keep just one XML for all Joomla versions?
please guide..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have more differences than that. There have been some changes from 1.5 to 1.6+ that are required.

The good news is that Joomla will ignore anything in an install package that it does not recognize so you can safely put everything for multiple versions in one package. Also lucky for you, the Joomla documentation is pretty good for this exact subject.

XML configuration file instructions - http://docs.joomla.org/Making_single_installation_packages_for_Joomla!_1.5,_1.6_and_1.7#One_XML_configuration_file.2C_multiple_Joomla.21_versions

Single install package for multiple versions - http://docs.joomla.org/Making_single_installation_packages_for_Joomla!_1.5,_1.6_and_1.7

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code from [JCE for joomla 2.5](http://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/downloads/editor/joomla-25/category/joomla-25):

```
<install type="component" version="1.5.0" method="upgrade">
```

So I guess if you simply do the same it will run on higher versions.

Answer (score 0):

Just remember that the parameters has changed between J1.5 - J 1.6. You can specify them in the same XML-file though:

example:

```
<!-- Standard plugin parameters for Joomla! 1.5 -->
<params>
     <param name="paramname" type="text"  default="" label="" description=""/>
</params>

<!-- Standard plugin parameters for Joomla! 1.6+ -->
<config>
     <fields>
           <field name="paramname" type="text"  default="" label="" description=""/>
     </fields>
</config>
```